# How to limit velocity of object on touchDragged event?

Tags: java, libgdx

I am using the current code to handle the movement of the player ship in my libGDX game:

```
if (playerShipTouched)
{
  position.x = screenX - touchOffset;

  // limit movement to screen bounds
  if (position.x < 0)
  {
    position.x = 0;
  }
  else if (position.x > (globals.VIRTUAL_WIDTH - playerShipSprite.getWidth()))
  {
    position.x = globals.VIRTUAL_WIDTH - playerShipSprite.getWidth();
  }
}
```

This gives me 1:1 screen to touch movement of the ship. However, I would prefer to limit the movement velocity so the ship can't just skip to the other end of the screen if the user moves their finger fast enough. I tried something like this:

```
position.x = position.x + Math.signum(screenX - position.x) * 800 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
```

The movement is correctly restricted, but is jerky. Any ideas?

***edit***

Additional overridden touch methods:

```
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button)
{
    touchPos.x = screenX;
    touchPos.y = screenY;
    touchPos.z = 0;

    camera.unproject(touchPos, globals.resizeViewport.x, globals.resizeViewport.y,
            globals.resizeViewport.width, globals.resizeViewport.height);

    // Did the player touch the ship?
    touchRect.x = position.x;
    touchRect.y = position.y;

    if (touchRect.contains(screenX, screenY))
    {
        playerShipTouched = true;
        touchOffset = screenX - position.x;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button)
{
    playerShipTouched = false;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [MathUtils.lerp](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/MathUtils.html#lerp-float-float-float-) function to interpolate between current position and target position. Reduce the final argument until you get a smooth movement.

```
position.x = MathUtils.lerp(position.x,(screenX - touchOffset),0.2f)
```

Another option could be to add a speed cap on the player.

```
float speed = 16f;
if((screenX - touchOffset) < player.x){
    player.x-= (speed  * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
}else if((screenX - touchOffset) > player.x){
    player.x+= (speed  * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
}
```

Comment: I tried that, with a range of float values, but it still doesn't feel right when making smaller movements. It doesn't feel smooth.

Comment: The range should always be between 0-1. If none of these are suitable for you then we should look into something else. What sort of issue did you have with the lerp? was it due to the variable speed? or how it slows down the closer you get to the target?

Comment: Variable speed. Small movements don't feel smooth, ship movement is jerky. I tested with a range of float in the range 0 to 1.

Comment: I've added a continuous speed version to my answer. If this doesn't work, check you're getting 60FPS and that the touch event isn't too processing heavy as that could cause the stuttering of the ship.

Comment: I tried your new code, and I had to increase the speed to 1000f to get it to move fast enough, but the movement is still jerky. See here: https://youtu.be/VtdjI00zYgM

Comment: Is your player.x value a float? or an int? if its an int it may be loosing precision.

Comment: position is a Vector2, so yes, x is a float.

Comment: Well its non of the common issues I'm aware of. You're going to have to post a link to the code or a working example for me to be able to help.

Comment: I've added the only other input methods that I've overridden to the OP.